# Problems with fetching and adding arrays from DB query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have problems with fetching arrays from my DBcon Queries.

My tables look like this:

`tbl_current_userconnections:`

```
 user_id  |  connection_id
---------------------------
    1     |     5
    1     |     6
```

`tbl_former_userconnections:`

```
 user_id  |  connection_id
---------------------------
          |      
          |
```

Lets say the active user is the user with ID = 1. This user somehow calls my php-code. With the code posted below I expect the result of `$MessengerString` to be `5,6`. But as it turns out the result is `5,5`. I absolutely do not understand why. Can someone please point out what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance!

```
$curContacts = $DBcon->query("SELECT connection_id FROM tbl_current_userconnections WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$count1=$curContacts->num_rows;

$forContacts = $DBcon->query("SELECT connection_id FROM tbl_former_userconnections WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$count2=$forContacts->num_rows;


if ($count1!==0 && $count2!==0) {

    $curContacts=$curContacts->fetch_array();

    $forContacts=$forContacts->fetch_array();

    $MessengerArray = array_merge($curContacts, $forContacts);



} else if ($count1==0 && $count2!==0) {

    $MessengerArray = $forContacts->fetch_array();



//this will be the case:
} else if ($count1!==0 && $count2==0) {

    $MessengerArray = $curContacts->fetch_array();



} else {

    $MessengerArray = '';

}


$MessengerString = implode(',',$MessengerArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch_array()` by default returns two arrays - an associative and a numeric array - per row, which is why you are seeing only two of the first row. Using `fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)` should return a numerical array that you can `implode`.

If that doesn't work, try iterating over the results like this to create your array. ([taken from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $MessengerArray[] = $row;
}
```